# Querying list of servers with PS to report on Scheduled Tasks

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I work in a Windows environment where Scheduled Tasks have never been documented or kept up with, leaving us with about 150 servers that have a random smattering of tasks. I am attempting to construct something that will query specific information about these tasks and output them in a pretty format that I can sort through.

Here is what I have currently cobbled together:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$VerbosePreference = "continue"
$list = (Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(&(objectcategory=computer)(OperatingSystem=*server*))").Name
$logfilepath = "$home\Desktop\TasksLog.txt"
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

invoke-command -ComputerName $list -ScriptBlock { $sched = New-Object -Com "Schedule.Service"
$sched.Connect()
$out = @()
$sched.GetFolder("\").GetTasks(0) | % {
    $xml = [xml]$_.xml
    $out += New-Object psobject -Property @{
        "Name" = $_.Name
        "Status" = switch($_.State) {0 {"Unknown"} 1 {"Disabled"} 2 {"Queued"} 3 {"Ready"} 4 {"Running"}}
        "NextRunTime" = $_.NextRunTime
        "LastRunTime" = $_.LastRunTime
        "Author" = $xml.Task.Principals.Principal.UserId
    }
}

$out | fl Name,Status,NextRunTime,LastRunTime,Author, } | Out-File $logfilepath
```

The "pretty" part is a work in progress. However, if I am correct, this should query a list of server names from AD and then invoke the command on all of them, then output the results to the designated file. I have tested with one server...

```
$list = "Server1"
```

...but am hesitant to attempt to invoke these all at once. I am not even sure if this is the correct/most effective way of passing a list of servers to the invoke-command cmdlet.

Answer (score 2):

## Fan-out remoting

Calling `Invoke-Command` with an array for `-ComputerName` is perfectly fine. Note that it's going to call them one by one. If it can't reach some, there will be errors, but it's fine. It's sort of like doing:

```
$list | ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock { ... }
}
```

The above can be useful for helping you with progress, like if you wanted to do something like:

```
$list | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Verbose $_ -Verbose
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock { ... }
}
```

Or you could turn it into a `for` loop instead so you know the index, then you can calculate percentage and use `Write-Progress` to get some really nice progress info.

As for how effective it is, well, very, as long as you don't have a lot of servers and/or don't care how long it takes, since it's not going to run in parallel on all the machines.

### Other options for parallel remoting

#### Workflows

You could use a [PowerShell workflow](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/26/powershell-workflows-the-basics.aspx), which has capability to process things remotely and in parallel, but to be honest it's a little weird at first, and probably not necessary.

#### Jobs

Probably the easiest way to implement parallel jobs is to use [PSJobs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/12/31/using-windows-powershell-jobs.aspx). You would basically add the `-AsJob` parameter to `Invoke-Command`, but then its output is the job object. You have to retool things a bit to then wait on and receive the jobs and the data they return.

Jobs are a bit heavy though; they're technically entirely separate PowerShell processes, so if you have 2,000 servers, it might not be a good idea to suddenly spawn 2,000 powershell processes on your workstation to host the jobs, so be weary of that. Jobs would mostly be useful if you have ~100 or fewer machines, a good workstation, and maybe a lot of the servers timeout (so they take longer than the remote process needs to even run, and choke the whole thing).

#### Runspaces

PowerShell MVP Boe Prox has a [module called PoshRSJob](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob) that use runspaces as a more efficient way of multithreading in PowerShell, and it supports throttling too.

#### Just don't

Since you're just trying to generate a report that you'll look at later, I'd say keep it simple and just don't do it in parallel.